# Evaluating the energy of a wavefuntion (time independant GPE)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, quantum-mechanics, fluid-dynamics

Im looking at a condensate in a spherically symeric trap so the potential is
$$V(r)=\frac{m}{2}\omega_r^2r^2$$
When the interactions are weak we assume this wavefunction:

$$\psi(\boldsymbol{r})=\left(\frac{N}{\pi^{\frac{3}{2}}\sigma^3l_r^3}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{r^2}{2\sigma^2l_r^2}\right)$$

with $r^2=x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $l_r=\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{m\omega_r}}$
the energy is given by
$$E=\int\frac{\hbar}{2m}|\nabla\psi|^2+V|\psi|^2+\frac{g}{2}|\psi|^4 \mathrm{d}^3\boldsymbol{r}$$
with $g=4\pi\hbar^2a_s/m$
I know the solution should be

$$E(\sigma)=\hbar\omega_rN\left[\frac{3}{4\sigma^2}+\frac{3\sigma^2}{4}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac{Na_s}{l_r}\frac{1}{\sigma^3}\right]$$

The problem is the exponential term that pops up in each term of the energy integral casue you end up with a bunch of error functions and it doesnt cancel down nicely is there something im missing?

Comment: Quick tip: to denote Planck's constant, use $\hbar$ (code is ```\hbar```) instead of $\bar{h}$.

Comment: @K.defaoite Thanks :)

Comment: I'll have a look at this problem sometime tomorrow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies, I have been busy the last couple days. For brevity's sake I will rewrite
$$\psi(r)=\alpha\cdot \exp(-\beta r^2)$$
We can simplify the problem a little bit by only looking at the one dimensional integral (assuming the bounds are $[0,\infty)$ as per usual in quantum mechanics)
$$\int_0^\infty ...~\mathrm{d}r$$
Since $\psi$ is radially symmetric, we can take this as a constant and then just integrate that over $\theta\in[0,2\pi)$, $\phi\in[0,\pi)$. Recall that if $\psi$ has no $\theta,\phi$ dependence, we can write simply
$$\nabla \psi=\frac{\mathrm{d} \psi}{\mathrm{d} r}=-2\alpha\beta r\exp(-\beta r^2)$$
Which leads us to the one dimensional version of the integral in the question
$$E_1=\int_0^\infty \frac{\hbar}{m}2\alpha^2\beta^2r^2\exp(-2\beta r^2)+\frac{m\omega^2}{2}r^2\alpha^2\exp(-2\beta r^2)+\frac{g}{2}\alpha^4\exp(-4\beta r^2)\mathrm{d}r$$
If you're prepared to accept the integral identity
$$\int_0^\infty x^n\exp(-kx^2)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{k^{(n+1)/2}}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
Which is discussed [in this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843441/messy-gaussian-integral/3844178#3844178), then we can write this as
$$E_1=\frac{1}{(2\beta)^{3/2}}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(3/2)\left(\frac{\hbar}{m}2\alpha^2\beta^2+\frac{m\omega^2\alpha^2}{2}\right)+\frac{g\alpha^4}{2}\frac{1}{(4\beta)^{1/2}}\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(1/2)$$
The half integer values of the Gamma are well known. See [Wikipedia](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Gamma_Function_of_Positive_Half-Integer#:%7E:text=m%2B12%20is%20a,%CE%93%20denotes%20the%20Gamma%20function.). So we can make some simplifications
$$E_1=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\alpha^2}{2^{5/2}}\left(\frac{\hbar\sqrt{\beta}}{m}+\frac{m\omega^2}{4\beta^{3/2}}+\frac{g\alpha^2}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{\beta}}\right).$$

Comment: Sorry, I forgot a factor of $1/2$ in that integral identity. I'll correct it.

Comment: I have now corrected it.

Comment: Thank you that makes alot of sense also i really should have done the alpha and beta thing it makes it much easier to follow i always end up getting bogged down when a problem contains too many symbols so thanks for the super helpful answer !!! :)

Comment: @Yep You're very welcome.