# How do I solve this integral using Feynman diagrams?

Tags: graph-theory, quantum-field-theory

I have this integral which I want to solve to forth order in $g$:

$$ Z(g) = \int^\infty_{-\infty} \mathrm{d}x \exp\left(\frac{-1}{2}x^2 + \frac{g}{4!}x^4\right) $$

I can solve this integral quite easily by expanding $e^{\frac{g}{4!}x^4}$ and use this formula:
$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} x^{2k} e^{-x^2/2} \mathrm{d}x = (2 \pi)^{1/2} \frac{(2k)!}{2^k k!}.$$

But I want to solve it "using Feynman diagrams" and I'm not sure how to do that. Usually, it's the other way around, I calculate a diagram using integrals. So I'm confused. How does one solve this?

Comment: You can't compute an integral using Feynman diagrams, but you can write a graphical representation for it.

Comment: @Icv Thanks! That's what I thought. I can do this if I would have a correlation function.  But I don't know how to represent integrals of this nature with diagrams. Could you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the one-sided version of the integral identity you mention below is discussed in [this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843441/messy-gaussian-integral/3844178#3844178) if you happen to be interested in a proof of that fact.

Unfortunately you're not going to find a solution in terms of so-called elementary functions, but we can state the result in terms of the [modified Bessel function of the second kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ModifiedBesselFunctionoftheSecondKind.html):

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\left(\frac{-x^2}{2}+\frac{g}{4!}x^4\right)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{\sqrt{3} e^{-3g/4}K_{1/4}\left(\frac{-3}{4g}\right)}{\sqrt{-g}}$$
For $g<0$.

Comment: The OP is looking for a Taylor expansion in $g$ of the integral, but nice anyway.