# Integral of $(x+c)^n e^{-x^2}$

Tags: integration

As part of some convolution, I am desperately trying to solve the following integral:

$$
\int_a^b (x+c)^ne^{-x^2} dx \,\,\,\, \text{with} \,\,\,\, n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$

I am looking forward to any input! Many thanks!

Comment: Since your limits of integration are finite there isn't going to be a closed form answer (in most cases) using elementary functions. What did you have in mind?

Comment: I was expecting to end up with some combination of Error or Gamma functions.

Comment: I have a nice recursive proof of 
$$\int_{0}^\infty x^n\exp(-x^2)\mathrm{d}x=\frac{1}{2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)$$
[in this MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3843441/messy-gaussian-integral/3844178#3844178) but it hindsight it can be shown very easily with straightforward substitution as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the binomial expansion
$$(x+c)^n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} x^k$$
$$I_n=\int (x+c)^ne^{-x^2}\,dx =\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k}\int x^k e^{-x^2}\,dx$$
$$I_n=-\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} \,\Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2},x^2\right)$$
$$J_n=\int_a^b (x+c)^ne^{-x^2}\,dx$$ $$J_n=\frac 12\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} c^{n-k} \left(\Gamma \left(\frac{k+1}{2},a^2\right)-\Gamma
   \left(\frac{k+1}{2},b^2\right)\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

lets start off with:
$$I=\int_a^b (x+c)^n e^{-x^2}dx$$
let $u=x^2\Rightarrow du=2xdx\therefore dx=u^{-1/2}du$ and so:
$$I=\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}u^{-1/2}(u^{1/2}+c)^ne^{-u}du$$
and now we have to expand this:
$$u^{-1/2}(u^{1/2}+c)^n=u^{-1/2}\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}(u^{1/2})^kc^{n-k}=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}u^{(k-1)/2}c^{n-k}$$
so if we bring this into the integral and interchange the integral and the summation we get:
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}c^{n-k}\int_{\sqrt{a}}^{\sqrt{b}}u^{(k-1)/2}e^{-u}du$$
and we know that the incomplete gamma function is defined as:
$$\gamma(s,x)=\int_0^xt^{s-1}e^{-t}dt$$
so this would make:
$$I=\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}c^{n-k}\left[\gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2},\sqrt{b}\right)-\gamma\left(\frac{k+1}{2},\sqrt{a}\right)\right]$$